# PersistentVolumeClaim is not bound in RANCHER - Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, nexus, rancher, persistent-volumes, microk8s

I am facing a problem when I am trying to install Nexus using Helm in Rancher:

The error is the next:

```
creating 4 resource(s)
beginning wait for 4 resources with timeout of 10m0s
PersistentVolumeClaim is not bound: of-agile/nexusagile-nexus-repository-manager-data
Deployment is not ready: of-agile/nexusagile-nexus-repository-manager. 0 out of 1 expected pods are ready
```

The chart that I am using is the next one:

[image: CHART]

The STEP 1 is:

[image: step1]

The YAML is:

```
config:
  data: []
  enabled: false
  mountPath: /sonatype-nexus-conf
deployment:
  additionalContainers: null
  additionalVolumeMounts: null
  additionalVolumes: null
  annotations: {}
  initContainers: null
  postStart:
    command: null
  preStart:
    command: null
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 120
deploymentStrategy: Recreate
fullnameOverride: ''
image:
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  repository: sonatype/nexus3
  tag: 3.37.3
imagePullSecrets: []
ingress:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  enabled: false
  hostPath: /
  hostRepo: repo.demo
  tls: []
nameOverride: ''
nexus:
  docker:
    enabled: false
    registries: []
  env:
    - name: install4jAddVmParams
      value: >-
        -Xms1200M -Xmx1200M -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=2G
        -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap
    - name: NEXUS_SECURITY_RANDOMPASSWORD
      value: 'true'
  hostAliases: []
  livenessProbe:
    failureThreshold: 6
    initialDelaySeconds: 30
    path: /
    periodSeconds: 30
    timeoutSeconds: 10
  nexusPort: 8081
  podAnnotations: {}
  properties:
    data:
      nexus.scripts.allowCreation: true
    override: false
  readinessProbe:
    failureThreshold: 6
    initialDelaySeconds: 30
    path: /
    periodSeconds: 30
    timeoutSeconds: 10
  resources: {}
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 2000
nexusProxyRoute:
  annotations: null
  enabled: false
  labels: null
persistence:
  accessMode: ReadWriteOnce
  enabled: true
  storageSize: 8Gi
psp:
  create: false
route:
  annotations: null
  enabled: false
  labels: null
  name: docker
  portName: docker
secret:
  data: []
  enabled: false
  mountPath: /etc/secret-volume
  readOnly: true
service:
  annotations: {}
  enabled: true
  labels: {}
  name: nexus3
  type: ClusterIP
serviceAccount:
  annotations: {}
  create: true
  name: ''
statefulset:
  enabled: false
tolerations: []
```

The documentation say that:

*Persistence By default a PersistentVolumeClaim is created and mounted into the /nexus-data directory. In order to disable this functionality you can change the values.yaml to disable persistence which will use an emptyDir instead.
"An emptyDir volume is first created when a Pod is assigned to a Node, and exists as long as that Pod is running on that node. When a Pod is removed from a node for any reason, the data in the emptyDir is deleted forever."*

But at the end of the day I have the same problem as I mentionated:

[image: error]

And the volumens are really created:

PersistentVolumeClaims

[image: PVC]

and the PV:

[image: pv]

Any ideas?

Best!

Comment: Check the description of the Pod, events especially. From your screenshots, the PV & PVC are undoubtedly Bound. Not familiar with that wrapper: you  could try to deploy that Chart using helm directly: as one thing's for sure, Helm doesn't implement any check like this.

Comment: Could you please run `kubectl describe pod {your-nexus-pod-name}` and `kubectl get pv,pvc`? Please remember to check in namespace where you have deployed your application. In my case, as I tested, it took few minutes to fully establish a running pod. How long did you wait?